# How to set securementEncryptionSymAlgorithm to Basic256Rsa15

Tags: spring-ws

How can i set the property for securementEncryptionSymAlgorithm to Basic256Rsa15 in spring ws.

Comment: My understanding is **SecurementActions** is for outgoing request and 
**ValidationActions** is for incoming response.
 Kindly verify ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="securementEncryptionSymAlgorithm" value="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
```